# How to implement 3D carousel slider in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, carousel, react-native-snap-carousel

I want to create 3D vertical carousel kind of slider in react native. I'm searching over the internet past two days but no luck. Is there any library out there with below attached image style. As of now i used [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel) with regular style. It would be great if i get such kind of carousel.

[image]